# ERROR: cx_Freeze-6.5-cp38-cp38-win32 (1).whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, pip

**I tried to install:** `cx_Freeze-6.5-cp38-cp38-win32.whl`

With `python 3.9.1`

**I got this error:**

```
ERROR cx_Freeze-6.5-cp38-cp38-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Comment: cp38 means CPython version 3.8. If you have 3.9, then it will not work

Comment: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/78/f54fa018c93056d5fe032eee0b316d3bb8ea86423ad667d06c147b7caa0b/cx_Freeze-6.5-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl for the correct whl